# subtracting day subtracts month too in Java Script

Tags: javascript, date

In below code when I subtract day from date I get day as well as month subtracted by one.

```
var today = new Date();

today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);

var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;  //Here is the problem so I have to do +1 to get to current month
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
```

Anyone any idea why does this happen? Or if I am doing it in the wrong way can anyone suggest the right way?

Comment: I think you are confused , `getMonth()` always needs to `+1` because it starts from 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with javascript's `date.getMonth()` method, months are 0-11, there is nothing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Oh ya I just saw the details in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.

Thank you for the information guys!

Comment: Glad you solved it...according to StackOverflow guidelines though, this comment should be edited into your question rather than posted as an answer. And you should upvote and accept @birdspider's answer if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You've got confused.

[`.getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) returns day of the month, from 1 to 31.

But [`.getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) returns month index, starting from 0 (from 0 to 11).

*Blame Java legacy for that* ;)